# Creating a Mysql user within a Rails controller action

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Working on an app that wil be used by admin only to create multiple instances of another app.

In other words, `app A` will be used to create clones of `app B` on server and create all the configurations needed to run that cloned app on a subdomain `new_clone.domain.com`.

Managed to clone the app, created the `apache` config file, `unicorn server settings` file too. Managed to run rake `db:create; db:migrate` but I did this with the `root` user of mysql.

At the point where I clone the app, I generate a `database.yml` file for the new cloned app that has at this moment `username` and `password` set as `root`, but I woould like to have a different user for each cloned app.

The app A has a model called `Subdomain`, in the `subdomains_controller.rb` at the `create` action I do all the things, clone, generate config files, running rake tasks, etc...  and also   in this `create` action I need to create a new `Mysql` user with privileges for a specific database.

**What I have tried so far**, can't say I did much, I tried to run the mysql command within controller create action:

```
def create
  if @subdomain.save
    ....
    system "mysql -u root -p root; create database new_database;..."
    ....
  else
    ....
  end
end
```

but this puts my create action on hold until I type in the password, and even if I'll find a way to go over it I am not sure the rest of mysql commands will work. Probably there is a better way to add a Mysql user with one command line without going into mysql console.

Thank you.

Comment: Does your user have the privileges needed for database or user creation?

Comment: well, my root user yes, but that's the idea - when creating a new user it should have privileges to create a database and have all kind of privileges only on that database.

Comment: That command ask you for the root password just because there is a space between `-p` and `root`, check the `mysql` man page.

Comment: Don't think it's a good idea to play with mysql users from ruby script, it may be a big seciruty threat in the future.

Comment: @toro2k thank you, that was indeed a part of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood, your create method runs under Rails app with `root` mysql user.
Then you can simply execute mysql commands via AR adapter:

```
# Create DB
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \
`#{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(db_name)}` CHARACTER SET = `utf8` \ 
COLLATE = `utf8_general_ci`")    
# Create User
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("REPLACE INTO mysql.user \ 
(Host, User, Password) VALUES(\"localhost\", \ 
\"#{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(db_user)}\", \ 
PASSWORD(\"#{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(db_password)}\"))")
# Grant access
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \ 
`#{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(db_name)}`.* TO \ 
`#{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(db_user)}`")
# Apply 
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("FLUSH PRIVILEGES")
```

Comment: Thank you, you answer helped a lot, however I managed to make it a little shorter. I'll post it as an answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Yuriy's answer I got it working in a shorter way:

```
  def create_mysql_user
    @db_name = "#{@subdomain.name}_domain_production"
    @db_user = "#{@subdomain.name}_user"
    @db_password = "#{@subdomain.name}domain_password"

    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, ALTER,
        INDEX ON `#{@db_name}`.* TO #{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(@db_user)}@localhost
        IDENTIFIED BY #{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(@db_password)};")
    # Apply
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("FLUSH PRIVILEGES")
  end
```